# Facebook SDK (iPhone dev)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, automatic-ref-counting

I was having a lot of problems with the facebook SDK.
I've managed through them whole except these two problems:

> Facebook.m:52:9: error: existing ivar '_sessionDelegate' for
>   unsafe_unretained property 'sessionDelegate' must be
>   __unsafe_unretained [4]

And the second:

> FBDialog.m:47:13: error: existing ivar '_delegate' for
>   unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be __unsafe_unretained [*4]

What could be the problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Facebook per se.  This is just about how to declare an id using the Automatic Reference Counting memory model.  You can set these to not use ARC in the Build Phases, Compile Sources for your target by adding the flag -fno-objc-arc

Comment: Ray, you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Facebook per se. This is just about how to declare an id using the Automatic Reference Counting memory model. You can set these to not use ARC in the Build Phases, Compile Sources for your target by adding the flag -fno-objc-arc
@Rayfleck